# Looping an alternating image source function

Tags: javascript

I've created a tool that allows users to grab the thumbnail of a YouTube video although I'm having some issues with looping. On entering a video's watch ID, the image displays however if you then re-enter another ID into the input, it doesn't change. How could I change the code in order to allow for looping/multiple image grabs?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Thumbnail Grabber</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function()
    {
        document.getElementById( 'inp' ).onkeyup = keyUp;
    }

    function keyUp()
    {
        var img = document.getElementById( 'image' );
        img.src = img.src.replace( /url=[^&]+/, this.value +'/maxresdefault.jpg' );
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="inp">

        <img id="image" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/url=example/">
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your replacement is *removing* the `url=` part as well. Assuming `this.value` is `"X"`, it would change the `src` property to `http://img.youtube.com/vi/X/maxresdefault.jpg`. On the next keyup event, there will be nothing to replace any more.

Also, don't forget of the case when a user enters a `&` character.

So I'd suggest `.replace( /url=[^&]+/, "url=" + encodeURIComponent(this.value+'/maxresdefault.jpg') );`